# For which values of $p \geq 0$ does the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{p}+x^{-p}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

For which values of $p \geq 0$ does the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{p}+x^{-p}}$$ converge?

I tried applying the p-test, but I could not get the integrand into a suitable form.  So what type of argument should I use?

Comment: For large $x$ Compare with $\frac{1}{x^p}$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910558/value-of-convergence-of-displaystyle-int-frac-sqrtx1x2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $x\gt0$, $x+\frac1x\ge2$; therefore, $\dfrac1{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\frac12$ and
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\frac12
$$
When $x\gt1$, $\dfrac1{2x^p}\le\dfrac1{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\dfrac1{x^p}$; therefore,
$$
\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}
$$
Putting these together, we get
$$
\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}\le\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\frac12+\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}
$$
Thus, $\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p+x^{-p}}$ converges if and only if $p\gt1$ since that is where $\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^p}$ converges.

Comment: What about $p < -1$?

Comment: The question specifies $p\ge0$.

Comment: Right. But your analysis seems to be working for that case as well.

Comment: How did you arrive at$\dfrac1{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\frac12$?  Is there a specific inequality you used?

Comment: @WhiteRice: Use the AM $\geq$ GM inequality. AM=arithmetic mean.

Comment: @WhiteRice: $$\begin{align}0&\le\left(x^{p/2}-x^{-p/2}\right)^2\\ &=x^p-2+x^{-p}\\ 2&\le x^p+x^{-p}\end{align}$$ Therefore $$\frac1{x^p+x^{-p}}\le\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

For $p>1$ we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{p}+x^{-p}}~=~\frac\pi{2p}\cdot\sec\frac\pi{2p}~.~$ This can be shown by rewriting

the integrand as $\dfrac{x^p}{x^{2p}+1}$ , from where we deduce that $2p-p>1$, since $~\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x+1}~$

diverges. Then, from the fact that the integrand lacks poles on $(0,\infty)$, the desired con-

clusion soon follows. As to its value, this can be computed by letting $t=\dfrac1{x^{2p}+1}$ , and

recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, then using Euler's

[reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to brush up the final result.